# How to sort and group together the elements in a pandas dataframe in the way I want?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by

For instance, I create a pandas dataframe:

```
data = [['nick', 3, '2023/11/22 10:05:00', 'A'], ['tom', 3, '2023/11/22 9:25:00','A'], ['juli', 2, '2023/11/22 12:05:00', 'B'], ['ewa', 4, '2023/11/22 9:55:00', 'B'],['peter', 5, '2023/11/22 11:00:00', 'A'], ['johan', 5, '2023/11/22 9:00:00', 'C']]
col_name = ['name', 'score', 'time', 'category'] 
df = df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_name)
```

[image]

There are six students from different groups, and they have different scores in an exam. I want to group together the students from the same group and then sort them in the group from the highest score to lowest. Then I want to put the group with the highest score in the beginning of the dataframe followed by the group with lower score. If two students have the same score, the one with earlier time should be put first.

I tried the code:

```
df_sorted=df.sort_values(['group','score'],ascending=False).groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x)
```

It groups together the students and sorts them in the same group. The new dataframe I have now:

[image]

It only partly achieved what I need to do. Peter has a higher score than Eva and Juli, so Peter, Nick and Tom should be put right under Johan, followed by Ewa and Juli. Tom should be put in front of Nick since the time is earlier.

What should I do next to achieve the goal?

Comment: group C and A have the same maximal score (5), so why would group C be on top?

Comment: Johan from group C and Peter from group A have the same score. The time of Johan is earlier than the time of Peter. Therefore group C should be put first, preferably.

Comment: OK, but imagine there was another student with time 10:00 in group C, would you interleave the groups? Anyway, I provided you with the general logic below, then you can use an infinite number of combinations

Comment: A group is a block with members only in the same group. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra column with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to add a group score (here `max`), then use this to sort the groups:

```
out = (df
   .assign(max=df.groupby('category')['score'].transform('max'),
           dt=pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
          )
   .sort_values(by=['max', 'category', 'score', 'dt'],
                ascending=[False, True, False, True]
               )
   .drop(columns=['max', 'dt'])
)
```

Same logic without the temporary columns with [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
import numpy as np

order = np.lexsort([pd.to_datetime(df['time']),
                    -df['score'],
                    df['category'],
                    -df.groupby('category')['score'].transform('max')])

out = df.iloc[order]
```

Output:

```
    name  score                 time category
4  peter      5  2023/11/22 11:00:00        A
1    tom      3   2023/11/22 9:25:00        A
0   nick      3  2023/11/22 10:05:00        A
5  johan      5   2023/11/22 9:00:00        C
3    ewa      4   2023/11/22 9:55:00        B
2   juli      2  2023/11/22 12:05:00        B
```

##### breaking a tie between two groups with the same max

Here groups `A` and `C` have the same maximum, if you want to have `C` on top because it has a greater average score than `A`, you can add an extra sorter:

```
g = df.groupby('category')['score'].transform

out = (df
   .assign(max=g('max'),
           mean=g('mean'),
           dt=pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
          )
   .sort_values(by=['max', 'mean', 'category', 'score', 'dt'],
                ascending=[False, False, True, False, True]
               )
   .drop(columns=['max', 'mean', 'dt'])
)
```

Or:

```
import numpy as np

g = df.groupby('category')['score'].transform
order = np.lexsort([pd.to_datetime(df['time']),
                    -df['score'],
                    df['category'],
                    -g('mean'),
                    -g('max')])

out = df.iloc[order]
```

Output:

```
    name  score                 time category
5  johan      5   2023/11/22 9:00:00        C
4  peter      5  2023/11/22 11:00:00        A
1    tom      3   2023/11/22 9:25:00        A
0   nick      3  2023/11/22 10:05:00        A
3    ewa      4   2023/11/22 9:55:00        B
2   juli      2  2023/11/22 12:05:00        B
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use just `sorted()` for this. I find it more readable than the accepted answer. I use `key=lambda x: (x.score.max(), 1 - x.time.min().timestamp())` to sort on the max score value and the unix-converted timestamp time (seconds) using `1-timestamp` to reverse the sorting order, else newer entries would go first.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time) #to sort on time

groups = sorted(
    [group.sort_values('score', ascending=False) for _, group in df.groupby('category')],
    key=lambda x: (x.score.values[0], 1 - x.time.min().timestamp()),
    reverse=True
)

new_df = pd.concat(groups)
print(new_df)


    name  score                time category
5  johan      5 2023-11-22 09:00:00        C
4  peter      5 2023-11-22 11:00:00        A
0   nick      3 2023-11-22 10:05:00        A
1    tom      3 2023-11-22 09:25:00        A
3    ewa      4 2023-11-22 09:55:00        B
2   juli      2 2023-11-22 12:05:00        B
```